# Lucene 4.2 analyzer while indexing fields

Tags: lucene, indexing, field, analyzer

I am trying to index a set of documents using Lucene 4.2. I've created a custom analyzer, that doesn't tokenize and doesn't lowercase the terms, with the following code:

```
     public class NoTokenAnalyzer extends Analyzer{
public Version matchVersion;
public NoTokenAnalyzer(Version matchVersion){
    this.matchVersion=matchVersion;
}
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //final Tokenizer source = new NoTokenTokenizer(matchVersion, reader);
    final KeywordTokenizer source=new KeywordTokenizer(reader);
    TokenStream result = new LowerCaseFilter(matchVersion, source);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);

}
```

}

I use the analyzer to construct the index (inspired by the code provided in the Lucene documentation):

```
    public static void IndexFile(Analyzer analyzer) throws IOException{
    boolean create=true;



String directoryPath="path";
File folderToIndex=new File(directoryPath);
File[]filesToIndex=folderToIndex.listFiles();

Directory directory=FSDirectory.open(new File("index path"));

IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_42, analyzer);

      if (create) {
        // Create a new index in the directory, removing any
        // previously indexed documents:
        iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
     } else {
        // Add new documents to an existing index:
        iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
      }

      IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, iwc);
for (final File singleFile : filesToIndex) {


//process files in the directory and extract strings to index
    //..........
    String field1;
    String field2;

     //index fields

      Document doc=new Document();


     Field f1Field= new Field("f1", field1, TextField.TYPE_STORED);


      doc.add(f1Field);
      doc.add(new Field("f2", field2, TextField.TYPE_STORED));  
      }
writer.close();
   }
```

The problem with the code is that the indexed fields are  not tokenized, but they are also not lowercased,i.e, it seems that the analyzer is not being applied during indexing. 
I can't figure out what's wrong? How can I make the analyzer work?

Answer (score 1):

The code works correctly. So it might serve someone in creating a custom analyzer in Lucene 4.2, and using it for indexing and searching.